# How to get row only if column value equals "joined_table1.id" or "joined_table2.id"?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 different tables that hold different types of products, e.g. `Phones` or `TVs`. Each of those two tables have a PK.

I also provide a catalog functionality, where a single catalog may contain multiple TVs and multiple Phones. In the `catalog_items.idItem` column I am storing the PK of the item being added to the catalog (but not its type).

My question is, how do I retrieve all `catalog_items` rows where the item is present in at least one of the two product tables, by just knowing the ID that is joining the three tables?

To visualize:

Table `tvs`:

1. id
2. Name

Table `phones`:

1. id
2. Name

Table `catalog_items`:

1. id
2. idItem (may contain a ID from either tvs.id or phones.id, but also may be a different product entirely; I want to exclude rows with IDs of other products besides TVs and Phones)

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure you don't have duplicate key values in the two tables? IOW, table tv.id can not exist in phones.tv.

```
SELECT 
    a.id as cat_id,
    b.id as tv_id,
    b.name as tv_name,
    c.id as phone_id,
    c.name as phone_name
FROM catalog_items a
LEFT JOIN tvs b
    ON a.iditem = b.id
LEFT JOIN
    ON a.iditem = c.id
WHERE NOT(b.id IS NULL) AND NOT(c.id IS NULL)
```

Not the best way to store the data, or the most efficient way to have to retrieve it. It would be much better to have all of the products in one table.

One alternative would be to create a view that unions the product tables, and then use the view in a simple two table inner join. This would allow you to order the results by any of the fields in the product tables.